# Show that (vector) subspaces of $\mathbb{A}^n$ are algebraic sets

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry, polynomials, vector-spaces

i have just started to learn some algebraic geometry and there is a statement in the notes i am following that i do not understand: "Subvector spaces of $\mathbb{A}^n$ are algebraic sets. They are of the form $Z(f_1,\ldots,f_n)$ where $f_i$ are polynomials of degree 1." (from notes by Lothar Goettsche: http://users.ictp.it/~gottsche/)

My problem with this statement is the following: For every point $a =(a_1,\ldots, a_n)$ in $A^n$ i can give a set $S$ of polynomials  such that their common zero set ist $\{a\}$: 
$S = \{x_1-a_1, \ldots, x_n - a_n\}$. But how can i find a set of polynomials that vanishes on a whole vector space ? Of course one can take the zero polynomial, but that would not be of degree one ?

Thank you for advice

readingframe

Comment: You have probably learned in your linear algebra course how to describe linear subspaces by equations...

Comment: "   But how can i find a set of polynomials that vanishes on a whole vector space ? " For example, in  $\mathbb C^3$ with coordinates $x,y,z$ , all polynomials of the form $ay+bz$ vanish on the $x$-axis, which is a sub-vector space of $\mathbb A^3(\mathbb C)=\mathbb C^3$.

Comment: I thought affine space wasn't equipped with a vector space structure? The definition I'm used to is that $\mathbb A_k^n = k^n $ as sets, and that the structure we place on $\mathbb A_k^n $ is a topological one and, in particular, there is no 'distinguished point' i.e. no origin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A sub vector space is an intersection of hyperplanes. Every hyperplane is the zero set of a linear form (hence a polynomial of degree 1). The common zero set of all these linear forms (which by definition is an algebraic set) is you sub vector space.

Comment: Cher QiL, hyperplan est féminin en anglais, donc hyperplane :-)

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg: Oui, je vais arrêter d'écrire in English ! Merci pour le moyen mnémotechnique.

Comment: I will try that. Lets say, i want to describe a two dimensional subspace of C^3. ax  is zero on  the y axis and on the z axis. Thus it is zero on the two dimensional subspace spanned by those two axis. Ist this the way to think about it ?

Comment: @readingframe: oui.